# symplectic structure on $S^2$

Tags: analysis, dynamical-systems

i was looking for a symplectic structure on the $S^2 $. Originally i considered the Poisson-Structure of a rigid body, which was given by $\{F,G\}=\langle \Pi, \nabla F \times \nabla G \rangle$, for $F,G\in C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^3,\mathbb{R})$ . It turns out, that the sphere $S^2$ is invariant w.r.t. this structure. At the moment i´m looking at functions on the sphere which i´ve multiplied with a bump-function $\varphi(r)$ to extend the functions on the sphere in to the $\mathbb{R}^3$. In order to use the Poisson-structure i have to calculate $\nabla F$ and $\nabla G$ w.r.t. the Cartesian coordinates. Therefore i used the spherical coordinates.
$\Pi_1=r sin(\theta) cos(\eta),
\Pi_2=r sin\theta) sin(\eta), 
\Pi_3=r cos(\eta)$ 
and with the Jacobian J i´m able to calculate the gradient in Cartesian coordinates by

$
  \nabla F=\left(\begin{smallmatrix}
  \frac{\partial F}{\partial \Pi_1}\\
   \frac{\partial F}{\partial \Pi_2}\\
   \frac{\partial F}{\partial \Pi_3}\end{smallmatrix} \right)=(J^{-1}(r,\theta,\eta))^T\left(\begin{smallmatrix}
   \frac{\partial F}{\partial r}\\
   \frac{\partial F}{\partial \theta}\\
   \frac{\partial F}{\partial \eta}\end{smallmatrix} \right)=\left(\begin{smallmatrix}
   \frac{\partial F}{\partial r}\sin(theta)\cos(\eta) + \frac{\partial F}{\partial\theta}\frac{1}{r}\cos(\theta) \cos(\eta)- \frac{\partial F}{\partial \eta}\frac{\sin(\eta)}{r\sin(theta)}\\
   \frac{\partial F}{\partial r}\sin(\theta)\sin(\eta) + \frac{\partial F}{\partial \theta}\frac{1}{r}\cos(\theta) \sin(\eta) + \frac{\partial F}{\partial\eta}\frac{\cos(\eta)}{r\sin(theta)}\\
   \frac{\partial F}{\partial r}\cos(\theta) -\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial F}{\partial \theta}\sin(theta)
   \end{smallmatrix} \right)$

Now we put $\nabla F $ and $\nabla G$ into the Poisson-structure. 
 $$\{F,G\}=-\langle \Pi, \nabla F \times \nabla G \rangle =$$ $$
    -\biggr\langle \left( \begin{smallmatrix}
 r sin(\theta) cos(\eta)\\
 r sin(\theta)sin(\eta) \\
 r cos(\theta)
 \end{smallmatrix} \right),
 \left(\begin{smallmatrix}
 \frac{\partial F}{\partial  r} sin(\theta) cos(\eta) + \frac{\partial  F}{\partial  \theta}\frac{1}{r}cos(\theta)cos(\eta)- \frac{\partial  F}{\partial  \eta}\frac{sin(\eta)}{r sin(\theta)}\\
 \frac{\partial  F}{\partial  r} sin(\theta) sin(\eta) + \frac{\partial  F}{\partial  \theta}\frac{1}{r}cos(\theta)sin(\eta)+ \frac{\partial  F}{\partial \eta}\frac{cos(\eta)}{r sin(\theta)}\\
 \frac{\partial  F}{\partial  r}cos(\theta) -\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial  F}{\partial \theta} sin(\theta)
 \end{smallmatrix} \right) \times 
 \left(\begin{smallmatrix}
 \frac{\partial  G}{\partial  r} sin(\theta) cos(\eta) + \frac{\partial  G}{\partial  \theta}\frac{1}{r}cos(\theta)cos(\eta)- \frac{\partial G}{\partial  \eta}\frac{sin(\eta)}{r sin(\theta)}\\
 \frac{\partial  G}{\partial  r} sin(\theta) sin(\eta) + \frac{\partial G}{\partial \theta}\frac{1}{r}cos(\theta) sin(\eta) + \frac{\partial  G}{\partial \eta}\frac{cos(\eta)}{r sin(\theta)}\\
 \frac{\partial  G}{\partial  r}cos(\theta) -\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial  G}{\partial  \theta} sin(\theta)
 \end{smallmatrix} \right) \biggr\rangle $$

My solution is the following: 
$$\frac{1}{r\sin(\theta)}[\frac{\partial G}{\partial \theta} \frac{\partial F}{\partial \eta}-\frac{\partial F}{\partial \theta} \frac{\partial G}{\partial \eta}]$$
I checked it with Matlab but i expected a symplectic structure and my structure is not defined at $\theta=0$ or $\theta = \pi$. Are there any mistakes in my ansatz? Thanks for help